# backing up specific files not all the sub-folders and directory

Tags: windows, backup

I have all my jupyter code saved in `/` which is the highest directory in my windows 10 machine. I have a lot of code files saves here and i would like to back up only those code files. My problem with windows 10 backup is that it backups all the folders from that main directory which is the top level and down; so music folder, video, and all software get backed up. I just want to backup my code files and nothing else as it is very space intensive to try back everything. Is there a software which will allow me just choose the files i want to backup and not the folders down the directory?

Comment: Can't you use something like Git?

Comment: I want something local not over internet, our internet connection is not very reliable!

Comment: Aren't you putting the horse behind the cart? Why not simply saving your code into a sub-directory, and have that backed up? Would save you a lot of headache. (side note: why would git need an internet connection? It works fine on the local machine or within the local network. You could even install [Gitea](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea) on one of your local machines to manage your code and issues).

Comment: Welcome new coder!  Do you mean saved in '/' or '\' ?  Are all the files you want literally sitting in root, or in a subfolder of it?

Comment: `I want something local not over internet` Git in no way implies internet.

Answer (score 0):

I can strongly recommend [SyncBackFree](https://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/index.html).  It is a comprehensive backup tool that will allow you to specify any files and folders you desire.  You can even set up multiple profiles with different groups of files.  It is free of cost, but not open-source.  It has a no-install version [available here](https://www.2brightsparks.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=9641), which I recommend.

I have personally used it for years without any issues, and have recommended it to many people.

From your question, it should meet your needs.  If you need additional functionality, they also have paid versions called SyncBackSE (currently $39.95USD) and SyncBackPro (currently $54.95USD).  A simple comparison of the versions is available [here](https://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/compare-simple.html), and a comprehensive comparison is available [here](https://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/compare.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy). It's already on board, is very customizable (w.r.t. to ecxlusion criteria etc). And does a pretty awesome job.

However, otoh you would still be well advised to consider investing a minimal amount of time in really putting your jupyter file in a subfolder. Just makes life far easier. I'd think, moving the files in the subfolder now takes less time in total than scripting robocopy finally (or even reading its documentation)...